# Not able to insert again after System.Data.UpdateException >> Unique Key

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2008-r2

I was working with LINQ in my asp.net application. I've putted a Unique Key on two columns of the 'ColorDV' table.  When trying to add a duplicated value like 'ss' I've got the result:

> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the
>   entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'TITLE_AR_ColorDV'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.ColorDV'. The duplicate key value is (ss). The statement has been
>   terminated.

but the problem is that after this exception i can't insert any record in any of the tables, because of the same exact exception.  I wonder if LINQ is trying to perform the same previous insert each time.

Please how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an object to the ObjectContext, that object stays within the list of objects being submitted to the database, so yes that is the problem.  Remove the object and continue, or if an edit try to use the Refresh method on the context to refresh the contents of the object to the original state.

[This has an additional approach](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c12bd8c8-231f-4dcc-a665-b048f7debbd7/); can't personally say it works though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's right. I tried DeleteObject and all things are working well now.